# How can i use opencv to get product images from market leaflet?

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, feature-extraction

How can i process a market leaflet with Opencv to extract products image?
For an example, I have this market leaflet:

[Example of market leaflet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3W1N.png)

[Result that I expect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4cno.png)

I tried using some image processing techniques like bilateralFilter, adaptiveThreshold, findContours, but is not so good, because I have to change some parameters to work in others market leaflets.

I was thinking in use ORB, SURF and/or FREAK and scrape some product image to extract features and then build a database of this features.

Example of my algo to extract product images from market leaflets:

```
img = cv2.imread(image)
grayImage = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.bilateralFilter(grayImage, 20, 21, 21)
threshold = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur, 250, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 249, 0)
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(threshold, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

hullContours = []
for cnt in contours:
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
    box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
    hullContours.append(np.int0(box))

hullContours = [c for c in hullContours if 200 < cv2.contourArea(c) ]

for c in hullContours:
    cv2.drawContours(img, [c], -1, (0, 0, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow("Image",img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[Example image input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3W1N.png)

[result output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLHhw.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What exactly do you mean when you say _process a market leaflet_? Currently the question is very vague.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the welcome. I edited the question and I added an examples for what I am expecting.

Comment: Ok, so ORB/SURF and other detector/descriptors are generally used for matching between at least two images. Do you have a _subset of all possible products_? If so, you can do it but I am pretty sure it would be computationally very expensive. Alternatively, you can do template matching (assuming you have all possible products as images).

Comment: Hum, cool. So if I build a scraper to get Images of grocerys from an ecommerce of supermaket, and then use this images to do template matching, will be good ? What I read about using detector/descriptors is that i can make database of features and then use FLANN or https://github.com/spotify/annoy to index/find features. (https://medium.com/machine-learning-world/feature-extraction-and-similar-image-search-with-opencv-for-newbies-3c59796bf774)

Comment: Yes absolutely, if you do make a database of features, you just need to match the features to the ones in the leaflet image. However, if you have the leaflet images in the same scale and the product image scale also stays the same, template matching should also work wonderfully.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I gonna try.